# QT Creator copies SQLite as empty database

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a sqlite file in the folder of my QT creator app. I even did Projects (right click) -> add existing files, and added it to my project. The file gets copied to the build directory. However, it contains no tables or data. I need the data in my database file to persist during the copy. Is there any way to ensure this?

Comment: do you mean you want to keep the data but change the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the database is not being copied, since attaching it to the .pro does not imply that it will be moved to the build folder.

**And then why is there .db in the build folder?**

sqlite if it does not find the .db it will create it, so you get the empty file.

The solution is to implement a command that you copy:

```
COPY_CONFIG = mydatabase.db
copy_cmd.input = COPY_CONFIG
copy_cmd.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}${QMAKE_FILE_EXT}
copy_cmd.commands = $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
copy_cmd.CONFIG += no_link_no_clean
copy_cmd.variable_out = PRE_TARGETDEPS
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += copy_cmd
```